# stuck with phpunit testing in laravel 5

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5

I am new in PHP. I tried to make a login form in laravel 5.
I have this controller method. It works properly.

```
    public function choosePassword(ChoosePasswordRequest $req,Client $client)
    {

    $fn = $req->input('username');
    $pass= $req->input('password');

    $req = $client->createRequest('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/app/users/create');
    $postBody = $req->getBody();

    $postBody->setField('user_name', $fn);
    $postBody->setField('password', $pass);

    echo json_encode($postBody->getFields());

    echo $response = $client->send($req);
   }
```

and i am testing this with phpunit test. The class is given below.

```
class choosePasswordFormTest extends TestCase{

public function testStoreSuccess()
{
    $input = array(
        'password' => 'password',
        'user_name' => 'Abbas',
    );

    Request::replace($input); 
    Auth::shouldReceive('attempt')
        ->with(
            array(
                'password' => 'password',
                'user_name' => 'Abbas',
            ))
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(true);


    $response = $this->action('POST', 'GitController@choosePasswords');
    $content = $response->getContent();
    $data = json_decode($response->getContent());

}}
```

It shows following error. I don't understand what to do. Please help.

> ```
>     PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method choosePasswordFormTest::getInputSource() in /home/webapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php on line 520
> PHP Stack trace:
> PHP   1. {main}() /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:0
> PHP   2. IDE_Base_PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:500
> PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:243
> PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() phar:///home/webapp/phpunit.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:186
> PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /home/webapp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:425
> PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() /home/webapp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:751
> PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() /home/webapp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:722
> PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() /home/webapp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php:643
> PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() /home/webapp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:766
> PHP  10. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() /home/webapp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:881
> PHP  11. choosePasswordFormTest->testStoreSuccess() /home/webapp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:881
> PHP  12. Illuminate\Http\Request->replace() /home/webapp/tests/choosePasswordFormTest.php:16
> ```

Comment: Please show us the error message you are getting . Otherwise its hard to tell whats wrong with your code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably related to the fact that L5 is not in beta - and Taylor is still working on the testing code. It is due to enter beta next week, so I'd wait until then.

There are other issues in the current alpha L5 for phpunit - like this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6373#issuecomment-68617032

So keep an eye on that - and when thats fixed - try a fresh install of L5 and see if it fixes your problem.